# Datatable show column on the basis of result from server

Tags: datatables

I have four options for user on my page, I am showing data using datatable.
On Page load I show data for 1st option which contains 9 columns.
My 2nd option contains data which requires only 4 columns.
My 3rd option requires 5 columns.

I don't know how to change these column numbers and column name dynamically on the basis of user selection

I am getting this data from server in json format

Is there any way to do this ? I am doing this using jquery

I have also tried the option : "aoColumns" , and I have passed an array as my column names but it did not worked.

This is my code for table :

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" aria-describedby="bTable2_info" style="width: 100%;">
        <thead>
        </thead>


      </table>
```

And this is my code for datatable properties:

```
var col = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
           oTable12= $('#example').dataTable({
           "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
           "iDisplayLength": 5,
           "aoColumns": col,
           });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of the columns using the API fnSetColumnVis(index,boolean).

[Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jj4x5wb9/)

```
var dt1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    dt1= $("#t1").dataTable({
        aoColumns:[null,null,null,null,{bVisible:false}]
    });
});

$('#b1').on('click',function() {
   dt1.fnSetColumnVis( 1, false );
   dt1.fnSetColumnVis(3,false);
}
);
```

datatable site has quite a lot examples - http://legacy.datatables.net/examples/

Comment: Is there any way to directly change the whole structure of datatable I mean number of columns and names.

I want the whole new datatable , The solution you provided will contain the columns , I don't want that I want the whole new datatable with the data which I am getting from server with the new number of columns and names

Thank you very much for  your reply.

Comment: If you have totally different data set to show the better option is have 3 table templates and do DOM manipulation to paint/remove based on user selection. Datatable API can definitely be used to get around but I believe you are better off creating 3 different tables to keep your code clean.

Comment: Friend I found answer , trying to implement it , If successful I will let you know.

Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: Done,

you can save all the key names in an array then pass the array to sTitle it works

This is my code :

  for (var i=0; i < columnnames.length; i++ ) {
      tableColumn.push({
                "sTitle": columnnames[i],
                "aTargets": [i]
       });
       };